# Enable entering element when parent is in hover

Tags: html, css, sass

Layout is simple, make popups in the pins. I have made this simple HTML:

```
<div class="pin">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="arrow1"></div>
    <div class="arrow2"></div>
    <div class="content">
      text...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you hover the `.pin` element, popup should show up with fade animation. So `.popup` element has CSS:

```
z-index: -1;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
```

And when you hover the `.pin`, then this CSS will apply (note I use SASS/SCSS syntax):

```
&:hover, &.active {
  .popup {
    z-index: 9;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Full working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zohy37x/)

I use `z-index`-s because of my problem: popup will show up even when you enter the place, where the `.popup` element should be. Which is logical, since it has just `opacity: 0;`, but how can I fix it? That `.popup` should open ONLY when you hover the `.pin` and after that you could move your mouse into the `.popup` element, for example, to select a text. I know I can do it with `display: none / block;`, but then I will have no animations. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `visibility`

***[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6zohy37x/1/)***

Initially:

```
visibility: hidden;      /* add this */
opacity: 0;
transition: 0.3s;
```

When pin is hovered:

```
visibility: visible;     /* and this */
opacity: 1;
```

Comment: Man, you saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: @debute :D glad to hear that ;) no problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointer-events`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zohy37x/3/)

```
  .popup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -218px;
    width: 230px;
    font-size: 13px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
    pointer-events: none;           /*  added property  */
```

```
   &:hover, &.active {
    .popup {
      z-index: 9;
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto;         /*  added property  */
    }
  }
```